# phpmyadmin wont let me create a database

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

It says #1044 - Access denied for user "@'localhost' to database 'magento1'

I'm trying to set up Magento CMS and I got to this step and suddenly it won't let me create a new database.

I'm on Magento 2.2.5. Latest Wamp server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It say what your password is incorrect .
Check or change password.
And try